# Is there a name for a radical field extension of the rationals that contains all radical/solvable elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, nested-radicals

I am wondering if there exists a name for the field $F$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset F\subset \mathbb{A}$, and $F$ contains all the radical elements such as $\sqrt[7]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[4]{7}}, \sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{4-\sqrt[5]{2}}}$, but not unsolvable elements such as the roots of $x^5+x+1$ ?

Comment: Is this the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240951/name-for-numbers-that-are-solutions-to-equations-that-are-solvable-by-radicals?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677057/name-for-numbers-expressible-as-radicals?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590563/algebraic-numbers-expressible-in-terms-of-real-valued-radicals

Comment: thanks, I did chase through the resources to the answers to those questions, and I found an explicit answer here
https://oeis.org/wiki/Algebraic_numbers
and they call it the arithmetic numbers

Comment: The ring (vs field) is sometimes called the ring of radical integers - see  [Heine's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30141/242) - is  every solvable algebraic integer a radical integer? (which is still an open problem).

Comment: The OEIS proposed name "arithmetic numbers" is nonstandard. I've never heard it used before (and it's far too vague to be a good name choice).

Comment: Isn't it the maximal solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? Or is that too naive?

Comment: I thought these were called *explicit algebraic numbers*, at least I've been using this term for many years (e.g. see this [25 April 2000 sci.math post](https://web.archive.org/web/20030113182104/http://mathforum.org/discuss/sci.math/m/267197/267201)). I recall seeing the name used in some of James Pierpont's publications (around 1895 to 1910), and elsewhere in some late 20th century literature. Around 2004 Brian Conrad told me (email) that he liked the term *solvable number*, **(continued)**

Comment: and so I used *real-solvable number* in this [26 September 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/L0q4dXJAEuk/m/djqrg7ZXqGcJ) when the number can be expressed without the necessity of passing through the complex number field, but I've since realized that *real radical number* is a fairly standard name for such numbers.

Comment: Actually, looking into this further, I think it was Conrad who used the term *real-solvable* -- preprint I cited in that 2005 sci.math post -- although it seems to have changed to *solvable in real radicals* [when published](https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/J5final.pdf), and I believe back then I wasn't entirely sure what term I wanted to use. In any event, it's not even clear to me whether you want real radicals only -- all your examples are with real radicals, but your context doesn't seem to suggest this restriction.