# Field containing Q and n-th root of positive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

What is the smallest field $F$ satisfying 1. and 2.?

1. It is a field containing $\mathbb{Q}$
2. If $ x>0, x \in F$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $x^{1/n} \in F$

In other words, $F$ is the smallest field closed under any positive n-th root.

Clearly, $F$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It doesn't have any imaginary number.

I guess such $F$ has a certain name.
Can you give me a link for more information (importance or interesting property) about $F$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530322

Comment: Describing $R/R^+$ and its Galois group seems interesting, with $R$ the radical closure and $R^+$ the positive radical closure of $\Bbb{Q}$.